# Google Http delete with body (Json)

Tags: java, json, google-http-client

I would like to send this JSON message below, with the HTTP DELETE method. 
For this project is necessary to use OAuth2. So I use the dependency google-oauth. Foreach HTTP request I use the dependency google client.

```
{
   "propertie" : true/false,
   "members" : [
      "String value is shown here"
   ]
}
```

In my project I used this code below, but I cannot send the JSON message with the HTTP DELETE method.

```
Credential credential = new Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod()).setAccessToken(accessToken);
JsonArray members = new JsonArray();
JsonPrimitive element = new JsonPrimitive("String value is shown here");
members.add(element);

JsonObject closeGroupchat = new JsonObject();
closeGroupchat.addProperty("propertie", false);
closeGroupchat.add("members", members);
Gson gson = new Gson();
HttpContent hc = new ByteArrayContent("application/json", gson.toJson(closeGroupchat).getBytes());

HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential);
HttpRequest httpreq = requestFactory.buildRequest(HttpMethods.DELETE, genericUrl, hc);
return httpreq.execute();
```

Next error occurs:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DELETE with non-zero content length is not supported

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: There is not a lot of solutions here: either you stick with the DELETE request, but as your error message says, you can't have a body on that kind of request, or you do it with a POST request, which will accept a body in the request, in which you will be able to send your JSON data

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your HTTP DELETE request contains a body, which it shouldn't. When you delete a resource, you need to supply the URL to delete. Any body in the HTTP request would be meaningless, because the intention is to instruct the server to delete a resource at a particular URL. The same thing can often happen for GET requests - a body is meaningless because you're trying to retrieve a body.

For details on HTTP DELETE request bodies, see [this SO question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/299628/4851565). Note that while request bodies may technically be permitted by the HTTP spec, based on your error message, your client library doesn't allow it.

To fix the problem, try passing a `null` value for `hc`, or a value that just wraps an empty JSON string (by which I mean using `""`, not `"{}"`).